# problema al sumar números en factura pdf

Tags: php

Hola alguien conoce la libreria xinvoice de php? tengo el siguiente problema necesito que el total de la factura me lo tome como numero de miles ya que actualmente me esta sumando el total neto hacia abajo pero como decimal y por eso me arroja ese valor en el total que he marcado con el circulo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente query

```
$data = $pdomodelObj->executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT '". $area["id_cotizacion"] ."' as invoice__no, '". $area["solicitar_autor"] ."' as invoice__no1, tv.nombre_empresa as to__address1, tv.direccion_de_la_empresa as to__address2, tv.pagina_web as to__website, '". $fecha_actual ."' as invoice__date, '". $area["terminos_de_pago"] ."' as payment__method1, '". $area["tipo_de_pago"] ."' as payment__method2, pro.iva as item__desc, FORMAT(pro.p_u,0,'de_DE') as item__qty, pro.cantidad as item__price, pro.descripcion as item__name, FORMAT(pro.total,0,'de_DE') as item__total
FROM orden_de_compra as oc INNER JOIN tabla_ventas as tv
ON '". $area["cliente"] ."' = tv.id_tabla_ventas INNER JOIN productos as pro ON '". $area["id_cotizacion"] ."' = pro.id_cotizacion WHERE '". $area["solicitar_autor"] ."' = '". $nombre ."' ");

$xinvoice->setInvoiceCompleteData($data);
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor tomate el tiempo de leer [ask], de paso checa el [tour], al momento tu pregunta tiene problemas pues es muy amplia, no muestra avance de tu parte lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: No deberías usar `format()` ¿Cómo sabe xinvoice que esta en formato alemán? Si sólo quieres quitar decimales usa `round()`.

Comment: como se usa round() ?

Comment: he probado round() pero no me funcionó

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código con el que manejas los valores que muestras en la imagen?

Comment: este es

$xinvoice->addInvoiceTotal("subtotal", "Total: ", array("item_total"));
$xinvoice->addInvoiceTotal("discount", "Total Impuestos 19%: ", array("item_total", "discount"),"%", 19);
$xinvoice->addInvoiceTotal("tax", "Total (Impuesto inc): ", array("item_total", "discount"),"+");